# How can I write .html.erb javascript function to hide header from particular pages?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, erb

How can I write `.html.erb` javascript function to hide header from particular pages?

Comment: Like how? Like if a user doesn't have certain permissions or is not logged in? If so, a simple if statement can work for that

Answer (score 0):

I advise against using JavaScript for that if you already use `.erb` and are able to do that server-side, in Ruby on Rails.

This way you will not have any "blinking UI" problems, as the JS code executes after the HTML rendering.

Let's see.

*app/views/layouts/application.html.erb*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <% if weekend? %>
      <header>It's the weekend, let's party!</header>
    <% else %>
      <header>9 to 5 again.</header>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, in for example *app/helpers/application_helper.rb* you can define the following:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def weekend?
    today.saturday? || today.sunday?
  end

  private

  def today
    @today ||= Date.today
  end
end
```

A combination of those two will result in one header appearing on the website on Saturdays and Sundays, and the other on the workdays.